# Postgres - Simplifying Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns true, false, or null

```
SELECT * FROM commentsvoted WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2;
```

After receiving the value I want to perform another query based on the value returned.

If it's true:

```
UPDATE commentsvoted SET votes = NULL WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2;
UPDATE comments SET upvoted = upvoted - 1 
WHERE comment_id = $1 AND posted_by = $2;
```

If it's false:

```
UPDATE commentsvoted SET votes = true WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2;
UPDATE comments SET downvoted = downvoted - 1, upvoted = upvoted + 1 
WHERE comment_id = $1 AND posted_by = $2;
```

If it's null:

```
UPDATE commentsvoted SET votes = true WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2;
UPDATE comments SET upvoted = upvoted + 1 
WHERE comment_id = $1 AND posted_by = $2;
```

How would I do this in one query?

Comment: I am not an expert on postgresql, but you cannot update two different tables with a single query. So, having this point clear, you can save the `true/false/null` value into a variable and the update using a `case when` in both of your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can do updates inside CTEs (common table expressions):

```
with t as (
      SELECT * FROM commentsvoted WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2
     ),
     cv as (
      UPDATE commentsvoted
          SET votes = (CASE WHEN t.value THEN NULL ELSE true END)
          FROM t
          WHERE id = $1 AND user_id = $2
     )
  UPDATE comments
      SET upvoted = (CASE WHEN t.value THEN upvoted - 1
                          WHEN t.value IS NULL THEN upvoted + 1
                          ELSE upvoted 
                     END),
          downvoted = (CASE WHEN NOT t.value THEN downvoted - 1
                            ELSE downvoted 
                       END)

      FROM t
      WHERE comment_id = $1 AND posted_by = $2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm not sure why but it's giving me a syntax error at SET downvoted = (CASE WHEN NOT t.value THEN downvoted - 1
                            ELSE downvoted 
                        END)